# node.js middleware to check mandatory parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using node.js and express in my current app.
I have created several middleware functions, each one being created like:

```
function loadUser(req, res, next){
  ...
}
```

I'd like to create a middleware that would check the existence of mandatory params in an express action. For instance, I have a /user/create action which needs nickname, password, email, ... as mandatory parameters. I would then need to pass this list of params to a middleware so it can check if those parameters exist in the req.query.

Any idea ?

**UPDATE**

I've finally done the following (in express documentation, there is an example of middleware that require additional parameter http://expressjs.com/guide.html#route-middleware).

```
function checkParams(arr){
  return function(req, res, next) {
    // Make sure each param listed in arr is present in req.query
    var missing_params = [];
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      if(! eval("req.query." + arr[i])){
        missing_params.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }
    if(missing_params.length == 0){
      next();
    } else {
      next(JSON.stringify({ "error" : "query error", "message" : "Parameter(s) missing: " + missing_params.join(",") }));
    }
  }
}
```

It is then called like the other middlewares:

```
app.post('/user/create', checkParams(["username", "password"]), function(req, res){
  ...
});
```

Comment: parameters being part of the url or query parameters? `/user/create/:name/:password/:email/` or `/user/create?username=...&password=...&email=...` ?

Comment: @Raynos, parameters being part of the query.

Comment: nice. just a question, why use `eval("req.query." + arr[i])` ? `req.query[arr[i]]` should make the job

Comment: also if you use req.param(arr[i]) you can check either GET or POST params

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing it as a dynamic helper instead of a middleware? It might work.

Comment: in this case it will be called after all the middleware, right ? In fact I'd like this params checker to be the very first function called (before all the middlewares)